# google map with marker not appear map

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have been trying to display a marker on the map when I click an address but the map is not displayed.

```html
<div class="gmap_canvas">
  <div id="g-map"></div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=app_key&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
```

```js
function initialize() {
  var latlog = new google.maps.LatLng(39.305, -76.617);

  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById('g-map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: latlog
    }
  );

  // The marker, positioned at map
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlog,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Comment: "Not appear" as in nothing happens, or do you get an error? Can you check the developer console to see if there are any errors?

Comment: nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `style="width:100%; height:100%;` to the gmap_canvas div.

```
<body>
  <div style="height:100%; width: 100%;"> 
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: <div style="width:100%; height:500px"> </div> its working thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, it is a classic Google maps api struggle.